# Jasmine use it to over ride and test a method that uses aiax

Tags: ajax, testing, jasmine

I have a JS file that contains many methods, ajax caller is constant.

```
function ajaxCaller(data,url,callback) { //standard jquery ajax call here } 

function method1(){ 
// ... does work ... then 
ajaxCaller(data,url,function(){ // changes the dom } ); 
}
```

How can I use jasmine to over ride the ajaxCaller method that is being called by nearly every method in my js file such that I can test that the DOM is getting changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have something like the code below, right?

```
function ajaxCaller(data, url, callback) {
    $.ajax(url, { data: data, success: callback });
}
```

In this case you can mock the jQuery `ajax` method so that instead of real AJAX request the function you provide will be called. It is possible to define the `response` you want to be "returned from the server". Jasmine `andCallFake` function will do it for you:

```
it ('when some response returned from the server, something happens', function() {
    var response = {}; // ... define the response you need
    spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake(function(url, options) {
        options.success(response);
    });

    method1();

    // and assert that something really happens ...
});
```